# Adding event Listener to Dynamically Added HTML Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the HTML

```
<input type="button" class="btnx" value="click me">
```

and the attached JS file

```
$(".btnx").on("click",function(){
    var newbtn = "<input type='button' class='btnx' value='click me'>";
  $('body').append(newbtn);
});
```

When I click on the button 1 new buttons are append to the body, but when I click on the new buttons(button 2 or button 3) why no more buttons are formed.

I googled and found to use ".on()" but still can't figure out why it is not working.

JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/93k9emL1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$('body').on('click', '.btnx', ...)` for that:

```js
$("body").on("click", '.btnx', function(){
 var newbtn = "<input type='button' class='btnx' value='click me'>";
  $('body').append($(newbtn));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="btnx" value="click me">
```

**Explanation regarding your code:**

The problem with your code was that the new element that you added to the DOM tree didn't have the `click` event attached to it.
The way to make this work is to attache the `click` event to the `body` element, and use the `.btnx` selector. This way the code will work with every click you have, also for new elements that you add.

Comment: Yeah It is working but what is the problem in my code ? I cant understand.

Comment: Added explanation in the answer, let me know if it was clear enough :)

Comment: Thanks, now i get it